# Echo VBScript results in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, echo

I've got a situation where I'm working with a program that uses a .bat file to run a script that then checks for things such as firewall, encryption, software updates, etc. The program runs the .bat file, which then fires off a VBScript to check for these values. The program I'm running then needs the result of this VBScript to output back into it as key value pairs.

Right now it looks like the program will only see and read from the .bat file as it runs. I've got the VBScript echoing out the results back to the initial cmd window that opens up, and I can see the results. I'm doing this by running the following in my .bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF
cscript.exe //nologo VBScript.vbs
```

It looks like the program requires everything to be echoed out within the .bat file. Is there anyway to take the results from the VBSCript and use them within the .bat file like this?

```
ECHO strVBScriptResults
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` command:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo VBScript.vbs') do (set "strVBScriptResults=%%a")
echo/%strVBScriptResults%
pause
```

Comment: The solution works, but I'm having trouble gathering all the information being echoed out. I'm expecting the following, "Microst Windows 7 Enterprise" What I'm getting back is just "Microsoft"

Also, how would I handle multiple variables? is it just %%a, %%b, %%c, etc.?

Comment: Try using `tokens` option: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //nologo VBScript.vbs') do (set "strVBScriptResults=%%a")`